# Which CSS properties create a stacking context?

Tags: css, z-index

I'm studying about [stacking contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context) and doing some tests with the properties that create a stacking context.

I did several tests and found that, in addition to `z-index`, of course, the following properties also create a stacking context:

- `transform` other than `none`;
- `opacity` other than `1`;
- And `perspective`.

Are there other properties that apply a stacking context?

Comment: `position: fixed` can create a stacking context on Chrom(e|ium)! There's a flag for it specifically in `chrome://flags`.

Comment: @minitech Yes, `z-index` requires a position other than static to create a stacking context. I believe OP is aware of that. Or do do mean that `position:fixed` creates a stacking context on its own without `z-index`?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Yes, the flag states that *all* fixed-position elements create a stacking context. I don't know whether it's a bugfix.

Comment: @minitech Oh interesting. `=]` Will check it out.

Comment: @minitech I wasn't aware of the fixed position chrome flag, thanks

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52937920/8620333 some properties will also create containing block for absolute and fixed element in addition to the creation of a stacking context.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

One or more of the following scenarios will cause an element to establish its own stacking context<sup>1</sup> for its descendants:

- The root element always holds a root stacking context. This is why you can start arranging elements without having to position the root element first. Any element that doesn't already participate in a local stacking context (generated by any of the other scenarios below) will participate in the root stacking context instead.
- Setting [`z-index`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers) to anything other than `auto` on an element that is positioned (i.e. an element with `position` that isn't `static`).

  - Note that this behavior is slated to be changed for elements with `position: fixed` such that they will always establish stacking contexts regardless of their `z-index` value. Some browsers have begun to adopt this behavior, however the change has not been reflected in either CSS2.1 or the new [CSS Positioned Layout Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning) yet, so it may not be wise to rely on this behavior for now.

    This change in behavior is explored in [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237713/is-chrome-regressing-regarding-z-indexes-or-what-am-i-doing-wrong/13237896#13237896), which in turn links to [this article](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/09/Stacking-Changes-Coming-to-position-fixed-elements) and [this set of CSSWG telecon minutes](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Oct/0115.html).
  - Another exception to this is with a [flex item](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#painting) and a [grid item](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#z-order). Setting `z-index` will always cause it to establish a stacking context even if it isn't positioned.
- Setting [`opacity`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency) to anything less than `1`.
- [Transforming](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms) the element:

  - Setting [`transform`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-property) to anything other than `none`.
  - Setting [`transform-style`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-style-property) to `preserve-3d`.
  - Setting [`perspective`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#perspective-property) to anything other than `none`.
- Creating a [CSS region](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-regions): setting [`flow-from`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-regions/#the-flow-from-property) to anything other than `none` on an element whose `content` is anything other than `normal`.
- In [paged media](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page), each [page-margin box](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#margin-boxes) establishes its own stacking context.
- In [filter effects](http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/), setting [`filter`](http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#FilterProperty) to anything other than `none`.
- In [compositing and blending](http://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/), setting [`isolation`](http://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#isolation) to `isolate` and setting [`mix-blend-mode`](https://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#mix-blend-mode) to a value different from `normal`
- In [will change](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-will-change/), setting [`will-change`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-will-change/#will-change) to a property whose any non-initial value would create a stacking context.
- In [masking](https://drafts.fxtf.org/css-masking-1/), setting `clip-path`/`mask` with a value other than `none`.

Note that a [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Block_formatting_context) is not the same as a stacking context; in fact, they are two completely independent (although not mutually exclusive) concepts.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>This does not include *pseudo-stacking contexts*, an informal term that simply refers to [things that behave like independent stacking contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html) with respect to positioning, but actually participate in their parent stacking contexts.</sub>

Comment: Oh, it wasn't a flag in Chrome 22? I suppose that's why it got moved, then.

Comment: @minitech From what I've read, it seems like the flag was introduced so you can disable the new `position:fixed` behavior introduced in Chrome 22 for back-compat.

Comment: @minitech Also from the linked article: "To test if your page is going to change, go to Chrome's `about:flags` and turn on/off "fixed position elements create stacking contexts". If your layout behaves the same in both cases, you're set. If not, make sure it looks acceptable to you with that flag enabled, as that will be the default in Chrome 22. "

Comment: @minitech: I revamped the answer and added a little footnote on pseudo-stacking contexts based on your deleted answer, although my answer doesn't actually include them as they may be confusing.

Comment: Very throughout answer, +1. But I'm wondering now, about those pseudo-stacking contexts implicitly created by `inline-block` and `inline-table` elements, do they have any practical application or is it something not worth caring about?

Comment: @Fabrício Matté: I don't think there are any practical applications, but it is worth keeping in mind when dealing with edge cases as stacking context behavior mostly affects positioned descendants.

Comment: Does the position 'sticky' auto create a stacking context as well?

Comment: @and-dev: Yes according to the rules given, because it's a value other than `static`. Whether it should do so only for `z-index` other than `auto` or for all values is unclear - that'll depend on how it eventually gets implemented.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. "Setting z-index to anything other than 1" - Does this mean that a positioned element with z-index:1 does not create a stacking context?

Comment: @and-dev: Oh, that's a mistake in my answer. It should be auto, not 1.

Comment: @BoltClock Added [CSS filter effects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764404/why-does-stacking-order-change-on-webkit-filter-hover/25764603#25764603) to the list

Comment: @Hashem Qolami: Looks good, thanks. No need to notify me in a comment as I will be notified of edits :)

Comment: ```-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch``` [creates a new stacking context as well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling).