# How to make sure an element is on top of all other elements in a page?

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

I have 2 elements: a **Dropdown Menu** and an **Images Slideshow**.

The animations are done using jquery.

The problem I have (Only in IE7) is that the **Dropdown Menu** is cropped by the **Images Slideshow**.

I need the **Dropdown Menu**  to be on top of the **Images Slideshow**.

In css I set the **Dropdown Menu** main **div** to: `z-index: 9999` and the **Images Slideshow** main **div** to : `z-index: 1`

I similar problem this would be fix but not in this case. What can I do?

Comment: Can you show some of the HTML? `z-index` might not have any effect depending on the HTML.

Comment: I dont know your situation, but in the normal world, IE7 should not exist anymore. Just leave it as it is. The only reason not to drop IE8 aswell is because it's the top IE version in Windows XP and it might be a bit too much users to ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**z-index** work with **position**

use also position 
like

```
 z-index:9999,
position:absolute
```

Comment: is the surrounding element of the absolute positioned dropdown menu position: relative? did you try to give this one a higher z-index (same as dropdown menu) too?

Comment: The problem is that I give position: absolute to the slideshow I get the a mess with the images slider

Comment: you can give any position you can try relative

Answer (score 0):

position : absolute; for the dropdown will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

`z index` only works when you also give the `position` option (absolute, relative, fixed)

Older IE's also require the parents to get an z-index to correct it. In the example below you want the div that has no id, this is the highest possible in the example.
If that is not an option, go for the next best thing (div#2 in the example)

```
<div>
    <div id="1" />
    <div id="2">
        <nav>Your menu</nav>
    </div>
    <div id="3" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you thoroughly understand stacking contexts for z-index:

- [CSS 2.1 w3c, Appendix E. Elaborate description of Stacking Contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html)
- [Which CSS properties create a stacking context? (accepted answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16148341/613004)
- [Detailed Look at Stacking in CSS](http://timkadlec.com/2008/01/detailed-look-at-stacking-in-css/)

Answer (score 0):

created jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/877xa/1/)

If you don't have z-index for slideshow, things should work normally. Let me know if you have z-index for slideshow.

```
#dropdown {
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
}

#dropdown .body {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:green;
    top:10px;
    left:0;
}

#dropdown.hover .body {
    display:block;
}


#slideshow {
    background-color:blue;
    height:300px;
}
```