# Why does stacking order change on webkit filter hover?

Tags: css, filter, webkit, z-index

I've noticed a weird issue with my stacking order when applying a webkit filter. Why, when I hover over the image does the stacking order change?

I'd rather not have to use z-indexing to fix this, as it breaks other site elements.

Here's my JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/r13ycy1p/

Please excuse Homer, I just needed an image.

EDIT: How can I reverse the effects to stop the absolutely position div from being hidden?

Here's my HTML

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="slide-content">
            <div class="slide-title">
                <h1>hello world</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="slide-desc">
                <p>a description about something</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130920142351/simpsons/images/e/e9/Pic_1187696292_8.jpg"/>

    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS

```
li {
list-style:none;    
}

.slide-content {
position:absolute;
color:red;
top:50px;
}

li a:hover img{
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* For Webkit browsers */
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because a value other than `none` establishes a [stacking context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html). This is documented in the **[spec](http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/filters/)** (which is currently in Working Draft status):

> **[2 Module interactions](http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/filters/#placement)**
>
> This specification defines a set of CSS properties that affect the
>   visual rendering of elements to which those properties are applied;
>   these effects are applied after elements have been sized and
>   positioned according to the Visual formatting model from [CSS21]. Some
>   values of these properties **result in the creation of a containing
>   block, and/or the creation of a stacking context**.

Also the spec states:

> **[5 Graphic filters: the filter property](http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/filters/#FilterProperty)**
>
> A computed value of other than `none` **results in the creation of a
>   stacking context** [CSS21] the same way that CSS opacity does.

Comment: Ah ok. Do you have any idea looking at my code how I code reverse this effect?

Comment: At first glance, it seems it could be fixed by [adding a `z-index` of `1`](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/r13ycy1p/1/) to the absolutely positioned element. However let me know if it doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: Nope, I can't use z-index.

Comment: @MikeJackson What about [reversing the order](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/r13ycy1p/2/) of the `img` and the absolutely positioned element in HTML?

Comment: That fixed it. That reversed the rendering so the image was sitting in the right place. Thanks for your help!