# Why does applying a CSS filter block the contained link? Can I work around this?

Tags: html, css

I have tried to create a minimal snippet that demonstrates the situation. The following HTML/CSS creates two boxes, one red and one cyan. Each one contains a clickable link. When I apply a CSS filter (as I have done to create the cyan one), the box is no longer clickable. My best guess is that this has to do with "stacking contexts," but I admit I don't know enough about them.

For the second part of the question, working around this, is there any way I can modify the CSS for the `filtered` class to avoid this issue? I am running into this in the context of a Chrome extension that applies CSS filters to images, so I would like a solution that does not require modifying the underlying structure of the site (the HTML) or significantly changing the way the site looks. I would consider it particularly useful if there were a solution that could be applied programmatically without introducing risk that other sites will now behave incorrectly.

```css
.filtered {
  filter: invert(100%);
}

/* I cannot modify any of the following CSS to solve this. */

div, a {
  display: block;
  height: 50px; width: 50px;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.outer:before {
    display: block;
    height: 50px; width: 50px;
    left: 0px; top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    z-index: 2;
}

.inner {
    background: red;
}

.link {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      <a href="http://example.com" class="link"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="position: relative">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner filtered">
      <a href="http://example.com" class="link"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not do it the other way? Put the div inside the anchor tag

Comment: Because it's not my HTML. This is for a Chrome extension which modifies images on websites using CSS filters. I can't arbitrarily rewrite the HTML of the site without breaking things.

Comment: It has to do with the stacking context created when you apply a filter, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25764603/4305494

Comment: @Ricky I appreciate the comment. I guessed that had something to do with it, but it's just not 100% clear to me how this specific situation's stacking is modeled by the browser such that the `::before` appears above the link when a filter is applied to the link's parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `z-index` of the `.filtered` element higher than the `z-index` of the `:before` pseudo class:

```
.filtered {
  filter: invert();
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```css
.filtered {
  filter: invert();
  z-index: 10;
}

/* I cannot modify any of the following CSS to solve this. */

div, a {
  display: block;
  height: 50px; width: 50px;
  left: 0; right; 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.outer:before {
    display: block;
    height: 50px; width: 50px;
    left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    z-index: 2;
}

.inner {
    background: red;
}

.link {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner filtered">
    <a href="http://example.com" class="link"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, I see my example isn't quite right. In the wild, it's the filter that's triggering it. Allow me a moment to fix the example code.

Comment: Let me know when you fix the original question.

Comment: I have modified it with two examples in which the only difference is the presence of the "filtered" class.

Comment: That does seem to solve the problem as stated in the question, but I could still use some explanation about why the filter causes this problem and why using a z-index fixes it.

Comment: Can you explain why it doesn't solve the problem as stated in the question? From your question: "is there any way I can modify the CSS for the filtered class to avoid this issue?" I'm almost 100% that this is what you can find in the answer :)

Comment: I think you misread. It *does* solve the problem. I'm just looking for further explanation.

Comment: Sorry! Thought you said doesn't :) my bad. I'll try to find the explanation regarding this issue.

Comment: To tell you the truth - it looks like a bug. I guess it's related to the way chrome renders the elements with the `z-index` or something related to that.

Comment: I'll try filing a bug with this example, then. Thanks. Would you mind deleting your first answer, since I've removed the initial example that it was addressing?

Comment: Sure :) no problem. You can also edit my answer and remove it.

Comment: btw, do you mine removing the `voteup` and add it in 15 minutes again?

Comment: Too late. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I'm hesitant to accept the answer as given because I am in part looking for an answer to the question "Why does applying a CSS filter block the contained link?" I'm filing a bug on the Chromium project now, and if it's accepted as a bug, then I know for sure that's my answer. Otherwise, I'd like to give this question a little more time to see if I can get a more definitive explanation.

Comment: Got it. Sure :) no problem. will appreciate it if you link the bug here.

Comment: In the process of doing my due diligence for this bug, I found that the same behavior appears in Firefox. That leads me to believe it's not likely a bug. I'll keep looking for an explanation.