# How to invert the color of SVG logo?

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

I have a black color logo (logotype.svg) on a white background and a burger menu with black overlay. How can I invert my logo to white when the overlay is active?
So i need to apply this `-webkit-filter: invert(100%)` for class **"logo"** only when the menu is active.

Here's the menu code:

```js
var burgerMenu = document.getElementById('burger-menu');
var overlay = document.getElementById('menu');
burgerMenu.addEventListener('click',function(){
  this.classList.toggle("close");
  overlay.classList.toggle("overlay");
});
```

Comment: Set or remove a class that applies this style on the logo, based on whether overlay current has the class `overlay` or not …?

Comment: I don't recommend using `filter` to invert colors in an image [because that will create a new stacking-context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764404/why-does-stacking-order-change-on-webkit-filter-hover) (which messes-up `position`ed elements and z-indexing). When I need to invert colors or similar I just create a second separate image, though I appreciate this doesn't work for dynamically-generated or user-supplied images.

Comment: Also, you don't need the `-webkit-` prefix for `filter` anymore. The prefix has been superfluous [since 2016 when both Chrome and Safari stopped needing it](https://caniuse.com/css-filters).

Comment: Is your `logotype.svg` image being displayed using `<img src="logotype.svg" />`, or as a CSS `background-image: url("logotype.svg")`, or as an inline `<svg>` element? I'm asking because _there are_ ways to dynamically recolor SVG images in a web-page without using `filter`, but it depends on how the SVG images exist in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code in css for inverting color.

```css
.normal {
  filter:invert(0%)
}
.inverted {
  filter:invert(100%)
}
```

You can set the classes with javascript to solve your problem.