# How to prevent an element with a filter from appearing on top of a element with float?

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-filters

I have two elements, one has a fixed width and is set to float to the right (red element) while the other is a full width block element (blue element). Normally, the blue element is behind the red element, as I expect:

```html
<div style="width: 5em; height: 5em; background: red; float: right;"></div>
<div style="height: 2em; background: blue;"></div>
```

But when I add a CSS filter to the blue element, it now appears in front of the red element:

```html
<div style="width: 5em; height: 5em; background: red; float: right;"></div>
<div style="height: 2em; background: blue; filter: brightness(0.8);"></div>
```

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour while still using float and filter?

Comment: You can add `position: relative; z-index: -1;` to the blue div. Filters change the stacking context

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does stacking order change on webkit filter hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764404/why-does-stacking-order-change-on-webkit-filter-hover)