# Make Ribbon Appear Behind Rectangle

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am trying to create a ribbon at the beginning of a rectangle. However, I cannot figure out how to make it appear BEHIND the rectangle.

Please see this codepen: http://codepen.io/gosusheep/pen/aOqOBy

The part for creating the ribbon and putting it behind the rectangle is here:

```
.rectangle::before{
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid $blue;
  border-top: 25px solid $blue;
  border-bottom: 25px solid $blue;
  left: -30px;
  top: 10%;
}
```

Even with `position: absolute`, and `z-index: -1`, it appears ON TOP of the `div`.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Codepen works fine for me, from what i can tell at least.

Comment: The pseudo-elements are children of the element within which they are created.  This is why you cannot move them behind their parent.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032856/z-index-of-before-or-after-to-be-below-the-element-is-that-possible

Comment: @AnthonyTJRivas, There is a border around the rectangle. The ribbon appears on top of it.

Comment: @wazaaaap, that's what my CSS tries to do, but it still doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Of course. I just haven't gotten to this post until  now. Work and all that jazz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening here is that apparently, the property `transform: translateX(-50%);` it's "overriding" in some way the `z-index`. My solution is just center rectangle otherwise, for example:

```
.rectangle{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/qyob8a8n/1/)

Comment: Nice one, I think we added that part about `transform` affecting `z-index` at roughly the same time :)

Comment: @Harry I swear I had not seen that part of your answer, it happens sometimes :)

Comment: Sorry if you felt like I was accusing. I am pretty sure myself that you wouldn't have had a chance to look at my answer and also create yours within around 30 seconds :)

Comment: Oh no, don't worry, just saying :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your problem is not because children cannot be positioned behind their parent but because you are using a `transform` on the parent. Using transforms affect the stacking context like mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148007/which-css-properties-create-a-stacking-context) by BoltClock.

One solution would be to avoid the `transform` totally and use `left: calc(50% - 100px)` instead to position the ribbon at the center (like in the below snippet). `(50% - 100px)` is used as the value because `100px` is half of the box width (50% is the center point of the parent).

```
.rectangle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #8080ff;
  position: relative;
  left: calc(50% - 100px); /* newly added */
  border: 1px #6666ff solid;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

li + li::before {
  content: " | ";
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.rectangle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #8080ff;
  position: relative;
  left: calc(50% - 100px); /* newly added */
  border: 1px #6666ff solid;
}

.rectangle::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid #8080ff;
  border-top: 25px solid #8080ff;
  border-bottom: 25px solid #8080ff;
  left: -30px;
  top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<p>put a pipe between nav elements</p>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>banana</li>
    <li>woof</li>
    <li>quack</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<p>Ribbon on the end of a rectangle</p>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='rectangle'></div>
</div>
```

---

If in case you can't use the above solution, then you could follow the approach  described below.

Assuming you don't have any other use for the `::after` pseudo-element, you could use that to create the rectangle and give it a `z-index` higher than the `::before` pseudo-element to make it appear behind the rectangle.

```
/* Modified */

.rectangle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

/* Added */

.rectangle::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #8080ff;
  border: 1px #6666ff solid;
  z-index: -1;
}

.rectangle{
  padding: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Below is a sample snippet:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  display: inline;
}
li + li::before {
  content: " | ";
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.rectangle::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid #8080ff;
  border-top: 25px solid #8080ff;
  border-bottom: 25px solid #8080ff;
  left: -30px;
  top: 10%;
}

/* Modified */

.rectangle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

/* Added */

.rectangle::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #8080ff;
  border: 1px #6666ff solid;
  z-index: -1;
}

.rectangle{
  padding: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<p>put a pipe between nav elements</p>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>banana</li>
    <li>woof</li>
    <li>quack</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<p>Ribbon on the end of a rectangle</p>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='rectangle'>
    Some content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution here, look closely at z-indexes and positions

```
.container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.rectangle{
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: $blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px darken($blue,5%) solid;
}

.rectangle::after{
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid $blue;
  border-top: 25px solid $blue;
  border-bottom: 25px solid $blue;
  left: -30px;
  top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

And your codepen edited http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJXeed working now

Comment: You removed the transform, which causes the ribbon to not be centered. It seems the transforming changes the z-index as others have pointed out.