# css special box-shadow of form

Tags: css

I have a form with orange background and a shadow:
[image: form image]

and I'm trying to make the shadow with css. 
the best result I got is here: https://jsfiddle.net/2f903rcr/

```
box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px #505857, 0px 0px 7px 0px #505857;
```

Somebody know to do the same shadow in css?

Comment: blank fiddle...share you code

Comment: This is dupe a number of times. But [here](http://jsfiddle.net/am0ts2fk/1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect stack with box-shadow and transform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31608365/incorrect-stack-with-box-shadow-and-transform)

Comment: @jbutler483 thanks! got it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your code and can't understand your image but there is something for you:

```
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2f903rcr/3/

Comment: It is very simple..box shadow will increase from mid to bottom and no shadow on top. You just gave example of how to apply box shadow.