# CSS transformed parent affect child position

Tags: html, css

Why are child positions affected when you transform the parent?

I want the blue box stay in the bottom right position of the yellow box. But when I translate the red box, the blue box will move to his (red) parent.

In real life box-red represents my ui-view in Angular. The views are sliding in and out. I can't change the HTML hierarchy.

See my codepen
https://codepen.io/benbesuijen/pen/GPOQjM

**HTML**

```
<div class="box-yellow">
    <div class="box-red">
        <div class="box-blue"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.box-red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;  
}

.box-blue {
  background-color: blue;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
}

.box-move {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use `translateX`? You may need to explain your goal as I think you're going to run into more issues down the line if you don't give a bit more explanation as to what's going into those boxes?

Comment: This is an issue i believe caused by the stacking context of elements when transformed. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148007/which-css-properties-create-a-stacking-context

Comment: @Dan, I updated my description. Stewartside, thanks, I will read it and hope I can found a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the spec: [The Transform Rendering Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-rendering)

> Specifying a value other than ‘none’ for the ‘transform’ property
>   establishes a new local coordinate system at the element that it is
>   applied to.

What that means here is that the blue element will become relative to the element with the transform (the red parent) - not relative to the viewport (like regular static elements)

However, we can solve this case by applying the transform to the yellow-box, and have the the blue one's `position: fixed`.

Below is an example:

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button'),
    boxRed = document.querySelector('.box-red');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  boxRed.classList.toggle('box-move');  
});
```

```css
.box-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.box-red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;  
}

.box-blue {
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.box-move {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

button {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-yellow">
  <div class="box-red">
    <div class="box-blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button>Translate red box</button>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I took the liberty to spice this answer up a bit :)

Comment: @Ben Besuijen If you found this answer helpful please do mark it as such. 

Also thanks to Danield for enhancing the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your only way is to use `margin-left` and calculate the size of the box. Something like:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
   var boxRedWidth = boxRed.getBoundingClientRect().width;
   boxRed.style.marginLeft = boxRedWidth +"px"; 
});
```

It's due to the `translateX` essentially making it a `relative` position object, meaning the `.box-blue` jumps into that as its relative parent.
With `margin-left` the `.box-red` remains as `static` meaning it doesn't become a relative parent to box-blue.

Comment: The whole transform property is making te object relative (happend also with scale, rotate etc.) I cant figure out why this is normal CSS behavior. Your answer can fix the problem, but I cant use it because margin has poor performance with transitions.

Comment: I think you have to forego the performance gain because I don't think there is another way. Unless @Nemanja answer works for you