# Element disappears when not setting opacity: 0.99

Tags: html, css

I created a responsive page which has a box with text and blurred background. The page is available here on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r480pggf/15/).

**The problem is:** `.content` element is not visible without setting its `opacity` to 0.99. Why?

**HTML**

```
<div class="content-box">
    <div class="content-bg"></div>
    <div class="content">
         <p>Text with blurred background</p>
         <p>Text with blurred background</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-image: url('http://hazor.iki.fi/2003/juhannus/isot/DSCN9068-Maisema.jpg');
    background-color: black;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-size: no-repeat fixed center center cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content-bg {
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url('http://hazor.iki.fi/2003/juhannus/isot/DSCN9068-Maisema.jpg');
    background-color: black;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-size: no-repeat fixed center center cover;
    filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}

.content {
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    opacity: 0.99999; /* Does not work without this wtf */
    color: white;
}
.content :first-child { margin-top: 0px }
```

**JS**

```
function updateBackground() {
    var contentBox = $(".content-box");
    var bg = $(".content-bg");
    bg.css("left", -(contentBox.offset().left));
    bg.css("top", -(contentBox.offset().top));
    bg.width($(window).width());
    bg.height($(window).height());
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    updateBackground();
});

updateBackground();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Why does the code not work without opacity?

This is because your `content` element seems to be behind the `content-bg` element. The `z-index` has no effect because there is no `position` property assigned to it.

#### Why does it work when opacity of 0.99 is added?

As mentioned by BoltClock in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148007/which-css-properties-create-a-stacking-context), adding a `opacity` less than 1 automatically creates a new stacking context (similar to adding `z-index` to a positioned element). This brings `content` element forward and thus it gets displayed.

#### What is the ideal solution?

Adding `position: relative` would make the `z-index` work as expected (which is bring the element above `content-bg`) and that would solve the issue.

```js
function updateBackground() {
  var contentBox = $(".content-box");
  var bg = $(".content-bg");
  bg.css("left", -(contentBox.offset().left));
  bg.css("top", -(contentBox.offset().top));
  bg.width($(window).width());
  bg.height($(window).height());
}

$(window).resize(function() {
  updateBackground();
});

updateBackground();
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url('http://hazor.iki.fi/2003/juhannus/isot/DSCN9068-Maisema.jpg');
  background-color: black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: no-repeat fixed center center cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content-bg {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('http://hazor.iki.fi/2003/juhannus/isot/DSCN9068-Maisema.jpg');
  background-color: black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: no-repeat fixed center center cover;
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
.content {
  position: relative;  /* add this */
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: white;
}
.content:first-child {
  margin-top: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-box">
  <div class="content-bg"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Text with blurred background</p>
    <p>Text with blurred background</p>
  </div>
</div>
```