# Can't click input

Tags: html, css

I'm a newbie but i have a problem on CSS and HTML. I can't click the input area.

https://codepen.io/carrie28/pen/poNZOoK   `codes`

Comment: Remove `z-index: -1` from all of your elements. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33217407/css-negative-z-index-what-does-it-mean/33217492

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `z-index: -1` in `.body` which makes the element inaccessable. Remove that at least from `.body`. What are you trying to achieve with z-index? Dont use rules you dont understand/ need.