# Do floated elements create a separate stacking context like positioned ones do?

Tags: html, css, css-float, z-index

Recently I lit upon [an interesting article about the CSS z-index property](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/what-you-may-not-know-about-the-z-index-property--webdesign-16892). I found it because I was seeking for an answer about why overflowed text from a preceding div was displayed above the background of a following div but not above the background of a span in the following div, like here ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1mk658eo/3/)):

```css
#overflowed {
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
#non-floated {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 300px;
}
#non-floated span {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

[image: an inline box inside a block box]

The explanation for this is the fact that a browser draws elements in a specific order, which is based on the so-called stacking order:

[image: the stacking order of a HTML/CSS layout in a browser]

So for the root-element in a layout and every positioned element, the browser creates such stacking order and then draws all these orders in, sorry for the pun, the respective order.

So this is why *inline elements and text* (those which create **inline boxes**) are drawn above block level elements, even if these block elements appear later in a document, like in my jsfiddle above.

---

**So the question itself**.

I still cannot find an answer why these **inline boxes**, if they are created, for inline elements and text inside a floated element are not drawn with other inline boxes which are outside the floated element according the the scheme of the stacking order above, like here ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1mk658eo/5/)):

```css
#overflowed {
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
#floated {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
}
#floated span {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

[image]

Here you can clearly see, that the text from the first div in the document, which is not floated, is drawn above (after) the span's yellow background, while the span is an inline element and according to the image of the stacking order above is supposed to be drawn after the floated container (its background and borders).

So does anyone have an proven explanation for this? I suppose that floated elements create something like their own stacking order, like positioned elements do, but I have not found any mention of this in the web yet.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point here, but you should note that you have only one inline element here : span.

Comment: @enguerranws, yes, but according to my understanding of all this stuff (I do not remember any proof links right now) in order to draw a page a browser creates some inline boxes not only for every inline element, but for every line of text (split by the browser itself in order to fit text into an elment, not by new line chars in the text). That is why I'm talking about several inline boxes

Comment: @enguerranws: There are three inline boxes in total: the text in #overflowed, the "text in the non-floated div", and the span. The first two are anonymous inline boxes, but inline boxes in their own right.

Comment: I just wanted to be sure there was no confusion between inline elements / inline boxes.

Comment: Agreed - that distinction can be important.

Comment: @user907860: Generally, when an inline box is said to be split, it is split across several *line boxes* - but the inline content still forms a single inline box. Confusing, huh?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers) specifies the painting order of elements as follows:

> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in back-to-front order:
>
> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).
> 3. the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.
> 4. **the non-positioned floats.**
> 5. **the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including inline tables and inline blocks.**
> 6. the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned descendants with stack level 0.
> 7. the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least positive first).

Floats do not establish stacking contexts on their own. They will only do so if they are positioned *and* have a z-index that is not auto (not counting [any of the numerous other ways an element may do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148007/which-css-properties-create-a-stacking-context/16148341#16148341)). Otherwise, they participate in the same stacking context as other elements, including inlines, with the following caveat (from the same link above):

> Within each stacking context, positioned elements with stack level 0 (in layer 6), **non-positioned floats (layer 4)**, inline blocks (layer 5), and inline tables (layer 5), are painted as if those elements themselves generated new stacking contexts, except that their positioned descendants and any would-be child stacking contexts take part in the current stacking context.

Since all elements in your fiddle are participating in the same stacking context, and your floating element is not positioned (#4), the inline contents of the overflowing div (#5) are painted *above* the floating element *and* its descendant elements, even though the floating element appears later in source order.

The *background* of the overflowing div (#1) is painted below that of the float, however, because the background of the float is considered part of the float itself in accordance with the second quote above. You can see this by [giving the float a negative margin](https://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/1mk658eo/6):

```css
#floated {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Comment: I think, the text "in accordance with the second quote above" in your next to the last sentence should be "in accordance with the **first** quote above". Because the second quote does not mention the order of paining and the first (overflowing) div seems to have nothing to do with the second quote. I think this can confuse someone

Comment: @user907860: I see where you're coming from. The background of the first div does have more to do with the first quote than the second. Hopefully my edit makes it clearer.

Comment: @BoltClock What does "...non-positioned descendants" mean here? I am thinking about the word descendants, is that referring to elements "inside" the element with the float property on it, or could it also refer to elements after the floated element, now flowing to right/left of the float. I am wondering, because I put negative right margins on a left float, and noticed that it is not in fact in front of block-level boxes flowing next to it (only in front of its background/border). Thank you.

Comment: @Magnus: Elements inside.