# Child element not overlapping scrollable parent

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a parent element with `overflow-x: hidden`, and `overflow-y: scroll`. Grandchild element of this parent has position absolute but still not overlapping the grandparent.
[image]

Instead of "North America" we see part of N and America.

For those who consider this as a duplicate question I have searched for whole day and none of the answers worked.

Comment: what do you mean by 'not overlapping'? I suppose you want the grand child element to be hidden partially (i.e. the part of it, which overlaps the "parent element"). Right?

Comment: I want it to be fully visible

Comment: Hah, I get it. You are expecting the scroll to appear on the y axis, but it's not there.
better provide an example html page, with CSS embedded in it within the <style> tag
But just from the picture I can tell, that the issue is that you element has position absolute, it's taken out
of the flow, it doesn't take any space inside you parent element. It's a long to explain it in a comment, but you can look into this question and its accepted answer about those 'contexts' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206085/is-the-collapsing-border-models-implementation-in-web-browsers-valid

Comment: Sorry, the wrong link, the correct one is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586972/do-floated-elements-create-a-separate-stacking-context-like-positioned-ones-do