# Setting z-index on a static element, with transform, different behavior in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, css-position, z-index, css-transforms

In relation to `z-index` and the stacking order between siblings - by definition only *positioned* (having `position` other than `static`) elements obey `z-index` values. Positioned elements will always appear above unpositioned.

However, setting `transform` and `z-index` on an unpositioned element shows weird results which are different on Chrome and Firefox.

Here are 3 unpositioned divs: https://jsfiddle.net/mz29Luwo/ 
They are stacked according to their order (which is normal).

Now here they are, with `transform` set on the second (pink) div, and `z-index` `-1`: https://jsfiddle.net/mz29Luwo/1/ 
In Chrome it doesn't change anything,
but in Firefox (49.0, Ubuntu)- it makes the 2nd(pink) div appear **below** the first one (yellow) - as long as its `z-index` is set to a negative value (doesn't matter which one). A similar effect happens if you also set `transform` on the 3rd div.

Why is this happening? 
Which browser shows the correct behavior? 
Are there any other properties (not `position`) which can cause similar things?
Is this related to "[the stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)" ? I don't think it should - creating a new stacking context applies to the children of the element, but this is something related to its siblings...
Is there a bug in one of the browsers?

EDIT: Putting `transform` also makes the div appear above the other ones - however as said - changing its `z-index` doesn't do anything further in Chrome, and in Firefox a negative `z-index` does.

Answer (score 2):

css-transforms says that an element with a transform establishes ["both a stacking context and a containing block"](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-rendering), but it doesn't say whether that element is a positioned element (at least for the purposes of `z-index`). CSS2.1 makes no distinction, as there is *never* a scenario in CSS2.1 in which a non-positioned element can establish a stacking context (with the exception of the root element) — there are [a variety of other properties that can result in the creation of a stacking context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148007/which-css-properties-create-a-stacking-context/16148341#16148341), but they are all CSS3.

For what it's worth, Firefox is the only browser that behaves the way it does. dholbert is suggesting in [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1256980) that Firefox's behavior is buggy, based on the interpretation that transformed elements are *not* also positioned elements. At the very least, fixing Firefox's behavior would result in interop across all browsers — at which point the spec should (I say that informally) be amended accordingly.