# When/How does z-index break stacking context?

Tags: css, z-index

My understanding is that z-index elements are [only stacked with their siblings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). I've also read that z-index ["doesn't work" with `position: fixed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218927/z-index-not-working-with-fixed-positioning). However, I'm using the two together and it happened to do exactly what I wanted it to; and I want to understand why.

I have a blocking div that needs to cover everything in the page except one element. The element is not a sibling of the blocker, which I thought would make it impossible, but it worked. What rule is being exploited here, and how can I predict if it will work in other browsers?

```css
.top {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.yes {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: blue;
}

.no {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.blocker {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <button class="yes">
    Yes
  </button>
  <button class="no">
    No
  </button>
</div>
<div class="blocker">

</div>
```

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. An element with `position: fixed` does work with `z-index`. This may be useful to you: [**Basics of the `z-index` property**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32515284/3597276)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every non-positioned box belongs to the same stacking context that's established by the closest ancestor that meets any of the criteria listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148007/which-css-properties-create-a-stacking-context/16148341#16148341), or the root element if there is no such ancestor. This means that elements don't have to be siblings of one another in order to participate in the same stacking context. They may share a distant *ancestor* (in HTML, every element descends from the root element), but they don't have to share a *parent*.

`.top` does not establish a new stacking context for its descendants `.yes` and `.no` as it is non-positioned and its z-index is auto. Therefore, `.yes`, `.no` and `.blocker` all participate in the same stacking context — the root stacking context. As a result the mere fact that `.yes` has a higher z-index than `.blocker` causes it to be painted in front.

Note that while each of `.yes`, `.no` and `.blocker` does establish its own stacking context, the stacking contexts they *establish* are not pertinent here; it's the stacking context that they *participate in*, and they all participate in the same root stacking context.