# Angular Animations Appearing on top of element it should be sliding into

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-animations

I have a div that is inside a list group that I am trying to have slide in/out based on the state of a toggle switch. The problem is, when the animation occurs, it goes in front of the div that I would expect it to be going behind for the appearance to be correct.

This is for Angular and Bootstrap 4. I have followed a tutorial on how to get started with Angular Animations and also tried to add styling to both the list group and the div (as well as in the controller) to adjust the z-index based on a few google searches that I completed.

The div that is animated is below.

```
<div class="list-group" style="z-index: 9">
   <div class="list-group-item">
      <!-- toggle switch is right here --->
      <div class="recurringSchedule border-top py-2" *ngIf="expense.recurring" [@slideInOut]>
         ...
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The animation is defined within my controller like so.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-create',
    templateUrl: './create.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./create.component.css'],
    animations: [
        trigger('slideInOut', [
          transition(':enter', [
            style({transform: 'translateY(-100%)', zIndex: '-5'}),
            animate('400ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateY(0%)'}))
          ]),
          transition(':leave', [
            style({zIndex: '-5'}),
            animate('400ms ease-in', style({transform: 'translateY(-100%)'}))
          ])
        ])
    ]
})
```

I expect the `recurringSchedule` div to slide down and up based on the toggle switch state respectively behind the list group or list group item. But it slides up/down in front of the list group so you see the entire animation instead of part of it being hidden.

**UPDATE**

Per the request in the comments, I created a stackblitz that demonstrates the issue.

https://angular-z2lavg.stackblitz.io

Comment: wouldn;t this be related to correct use of z-index?

Comment: @jcuypers I've been playing with z-index values since I noticed the issue because I thought the same thing. No combination has gotten me what I expect. I would expect to need to create the z-index value for the list group higher than the value for the animated div.

Comment: Maybe you can get some inspiration from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148007/which-css-properties-create-a-stacking-context on how you can make things work

Comment: @jcuypers no results, sorry mate.

Comment: any possibility to put together a quick stackblitz?

Comment: @jcuypers https://angular-z2lavg.stackblitz.io

Comment: any way to share in edit mode?  can only see output?

Comment: Sorry about that, never used before. Here you go, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z2lavg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are animating an element with `position: relative`. Positioned elements will allways have a higher z-index than static positioned elements. To fix this, I suggest wrapping your two `p` tags inside a div and giving it a `position: relative` and a higher z-index.

Here is your stackblitz with my changes:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdbzwg

Comment: While that gets it behind the paragraphs, it's still visible above and below the paragraphs. Once it goes behind the paragraphs, I don't want it to be seen.

Comment: just use -50% instead of -100% and a longer time all solved -)

Comment: Can still see it.

Comment: Had to take it down to a measly 20% instead of 100% so it wouldn't show above the div. Not much animation left at that point.

Comment: the height of the P element.  if you increase it manually you could increase it.  or try to move up the class "on-top" in the hierarchy. not sure

Comment: `<div class="on-top" style="height: 100px">` works for me, with 100%

Comment: I got it by placing the recurringSchedule div in it's own list-group-item below the toggle switch box and adding on-top class to all the list-group-items above the recurringSchedule one. Thank you for the assistance.