# Bootstarp 5 - Fullscreen modal relative to parent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

`BootStrap 5`

I'm using this layout:

```
<div class="row flex-nowrap">
  <div class="left">
     <!-- leftbar -->
  </div>

  <div class="main overflow-auto position-relative">
    <!-- main site content -->

     <div class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
          ...
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `main` is the main content area ( scrollable ).

I'm trying to use a full-screen modal inside main, but instead of it being relative to the viewport it should be relative to it's immediate parent (i.e main).

`.modal` uses `position:fixed` which won't let this happen. So I did this:

```
 <div class="modal fade position-absolute">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
       ...
     </div>
 </div>
```

But to no avail. It made it look messy. Is there a cleaner way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really think the following code will be cleaner than your solution but just in case here it is.

The idea it to create a stacking context, this way `Position: fixed` will not be relative to the viewport. A few properties create a stacking context (`transform`, … and probably some more).

In other words `transform: translateX(0)` on your `div.main` element will make your `div.modal` behave like it has a `position: absolute`.

EDIT: For more information about properties creating stacking context : [Which CSS properties create a stacking context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148007/which-css-properties-create-a-stacking-context)